# How to fix this syntax error and improve the code?

Tags: types, ocaml

I'm doing some kind of simulation of the game Sliding puzzle (see the description of the game https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_puzzle). So this is how it goes:

- First I made a new type:

```
type slidingPuzzle= {mat: char array array; mutable row: int; mutable column: int};;
```

`row` and `column` represent coordinates of an empty tile, `mat` is a puzzle.

- Then I made a funtion for printing the puzzle, for better interpretation:

```
let print_tile tile=
for i=0 to Array.length tile.mat -1 do
for j=0 to Array.length tile.mat.(0) -1 do
if i=tile.row-1 && j=tile.column-1 then
print_string " " else print_char tile.mat.(i).(j);
done; print_string "\n";
done;;
```

- Now I want to make the function which slides the cells in the puzzle. This should be a function which takes a puzzle and two integers as arguments. Integers represent a location of the cell that we want to slide to an empty tile. The output should be altered puzzle. But in the case when the location isn't adjacent to an empty tile or the location is outof bounds, it should return unaltered puzzle.

My try:

```
let slide tile i j=
if (i=tile.row+1 && j=tile.column) || (i=tile.row-1 && j=tile.column) || (i=tile.row && j=tile.column+1) || (i=tile.row-1 && j=tile.column-1) then
tile.row<-i; tile.column<-j; tile;
else tile;;
```

But I get a syntax error:

```
Error: Syntax error
Characters 597-601:
  else tile;;
  ^^^^
```

(An example of a puzzle : `let puzzle1={mat=[|[|'1';'2';'3'|];[|'4';'5';'6'|];[|'7';'8';'9'|]|]; row=3; column=3};;`)

How to fix this?

Comment: You should group together sentences in `then` clause using either `begin...end` or just parentheses: `... then (tile.row<-i; tile.column<-j; tile) else ...`.

Comment: Yeah, that's it, thanks. But when I call `slide puzzle1 2 2;;` I get wrong output. The puzzle should be unaltered but it's not. It seems that conditions in if statement are wrong?

Comment: Honestly, at first I didn't look at the logic at all- just addressed your syntax related question. Looking at the `slide` I think the last condition in `if` is wrong - you decrease both row and column, it looks like "diagonal move" that shouldn't be allowed I guess. So taking your puzzle1 definition `slide puzzle1 2 2` does the (illegal) move. Is this an issue you're looking for? Another thing - your slide function just changes the "hole" position, but doesn't swap the "tiles" as it is expected in the sliding puzzle - is it intended?

Comment: Might you find something like `i=tile.row+1 && j=tile.column` easier to read and reason about if written as: `(i, j) = (tile.row + 1, tile.column)`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in a trailing `;` in your `then` branch, here is the minimized example (run in OCaml toplevel named `ocaml`)

```
# if true then print_endline "truth is true"; else print_endline "oops";;
Line 1, characters 44-48:
1 | if true then print_endline "truth is true"; else print_endline "oops";;
                                                ^^^^
Error: Syntax error
#
```

And the correct syntax is

```
# if true then print_endline "truth is true" else print_endline "oops";;
truth is true
- : unit = ()
```

But this is not all. If you want to have multiple expressions connected with `;` in either of your `if` branches you have to delimit them with parenthesis (either `(` and `)` or `begin` and `end`, they work the same), e.g.,

```
# if true then print_endline "truth is true"; print_endline "I say!" else print_endline "oops";;
Line 1, characters 67-71:
1 | if true then print_endline "truth is true"; print_endline "I say!" else print_endline "oops";;
                                                                       ^^^^
Error: Syntax error
```

The problem here is that the `if` expression has higher precedence than `;` so it splits it into three expressions:

1. `if true then print_endline "truth is true"`
2. `print_endline "I say!"`
3. `else print_endline "oops"`

and the last part is an obviously not a syntactically valid expression.

The correct syntax would be,

```
# if true then (print_endline "truth is true"; print_endline "I say!") else print_endline "oops";;
truth is true
I say!
```

And since we are here, I would like to warn you about an OCaml caveat. Imagine the following expression

```
if false then print_endline "you will never"; print_endline "see this!"
```

You might think that it will print nothing, but,

```
# if false then print_endline "you will never"; print_endline "see this!";;
see this!
- : unit = ()
```

It is again, because `if` binds tighter than the sequencing operator `;`. Therefore we have two expressions,

```
1. `if false then print_endline "you will never"`;
2. `print_endline "see this!"`


The first one is predicated and will never print anything, but the second is unconditional. 

To summarize, if you have `;` inside your `if` expressions, always delimit them with parentheses (I prefer `begin/end`). Even better, try to employ functional style, so that you don't even need to ever use `;` in your code. OCaml is functional language and works much better with pure code. 


[1]: https://ocaml.org/manual/expr.html#ss:precedence-and-associativity

The root of the problem is that `;` breaks the `if` expression is it has hi
```

Comment: To add to this, and based off the question, formatting code is often a very helpful way to spot these types of issues. The question shows no use of indentation and very poor use of space around operators. The [OCaml Programming Guidelines](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/guidelines.html) are a worthwhile read.

Comment: and to add even more, it is better to use existing ide with automatic indentation, completion, and typechecking, e.g., Emacs or VsCode