# How to perform several operations under the same condition?

Tags: matrix, boolean, ocaml

I want to negate the chosen element of the matrix along with its adjacent elements.
My question is how do I make these multiple expressions happen without '&&'. I don't know the syntax very well.
I am getting-
Error: This expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type bool

```
let matrix2 =[|[|true;true;false;false|];
                [|false;false;true;true|];
                [|true;false;true;false|];
                [|true;false;false;true|]|];;

let flip_matrix matrix a b=
  let n=Array.length matrix in
  for i=1 to n do 
    let n1=Array.length matrix in
    for j=1 to n1 do
      if i=a && j=b
      then 
        matrix.(i).(j)<- not matrix.(i).(j)&&matrix.(i+1).(j+1)<- not matrix.(i+1).(j+1)&&matrix.(i-1).(j-1)<- not matrix.(i-1).(j-1)
              
            
    done;
    
  done;
  matrix;;
           
flip_matrix matrix2 1 2;;
```

Comment: Once you feel like you have a solid understanding of your question and whichever answer you find helps resolve, consider editing the question title. I think the problem you're actually hitting isn't related to `if` at all :)

Comment: You're right I edited it. Hope It's clearer now.

Comment: Ah yes. that makes it much clearer what you were asking. In ocaml `&&` is a boolean operator, it take two boolean values and returns a new one. To sequence statements, you interleave them with `;`, as you've identified :)

Answer (score 1):

The sequencing operator `;` is used to chain together several expressions,

```
<exp1>; <exp2>
```

means evaluate `<exp1>` first, then evaluate `<exp2>`, example:

```
print_endline "Hello!"; print_endline "World."
```

Note that `;` works only for expressions that return a value of type `unit`, i.e., that are evaluated only for their side-effects and do not produce any useful values.

When you need to chain several expression that produce useful values, you need to bound those values to some variables, and have to use the `let <v> = <exp1> in <exp2>`. This expression will evaluate `<exp1>` and bound it to the variable `<v>` that becomes available for expression `<exp2>`, which is evaluated after that. Example,

```
let message = "hello", ^ ", world" in
print_endline message
```

As you can see, the `<exp1>; <exp2>` is just a short-hand notation for,

```
let () = <exp1> in <exp2>
```

Also, note that  could be a `let .. in ..`  expression itself, so that you can chain an arbitrary number of expressions in OCaml,

```
let x1 = f1 y1 in
let x2 = f2 y2 in
...
let xN = fN yN in
final_result
```

Now, we're ready for conditional expressions such as `if`. It would be natural to assume that

```
if x > 0 then print_endline "Hello"; print_endline "World"
```

Would print

```
Hello
World
```

If `x` is greater than zero. But that is wrong! As a I described recent in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67403115/2625442), the `if` expression has higher precedence (priority) than `;`, so in fact the OCaml parser splits this into two expressions:

```
(if x > 0 then print_endline "Hello"); print_endline "World"
```

So that at the end only one of the expressions is under condition. As always in such precedence problems the solution is to use parentheses (or `begin/end`, which is the same), e.g.,

```
if x > 0 then (print_endline "Hello"; print_endline "World")
```

You can also use the more generic `let .. in ..` if you would like, it works without any extra parentheses, e.g.,

```
if x > 0 then 
  let () = print_endline "Hello" in
  print_endline "World"
```

albeit a little bit ugly :)

Answer (score 0):

Mutating assignment of an array evaluates to the unit:

```
utop # let arr = Array.make 10 0;;
val arr : int array = [|0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0|]
utop # arr.(0) <- 1;;
- : unit = ()
```

In this line:

```ml
        matrix.(i).(j)<- not matrix.(i).(j)&&matrix.(i+1).(j+1)<- not matrix.(i+1).(j+1)&&matrix.(i-1).(j-1)<- not matrix.(i-1).(j-1)
```

You are using `&&` to conjoin a boolean value with the result of evaluating `matrix.(i+1).(j+1) <- ...`, and that latter expression with be the unit. Of course `&&` only works to conjoin too boolean values.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

````
let matrix33 = [|[|true;true;false;false|];
                 [|false;false;true;true|];
                 [|true;false;true;false|];
                 [|true;false;false;true|]|];;

let flip_matrix matrix a b=
  let n=Array.length matrix in
  for i=1 to n do 
    let n1=Array.length matrix in
    for j=1 to n1 do
      if i=a && j=b
      then begin 
        matrix.(i).(j)<- not matrix.(i).(j);
        matrix.(i+1).(j)<- not matrix.(i+1).(j);
        matrix.(i).(j+1)<- not matrix.(i).(j+1); 
        matrix.(i).(j-1)<- not matrix.(i).(j-1);
        matrix.(i-1).(j)<- not matrix.(i-1).(j);
      end;
    done;
    
  done;
  matrix;;

flip_matrix matrix33 1 1 ;;```
````